# Request higher time frame data for external sources?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to get htf data for an external source within my code, but i can't seem to crack it. Any ideas?

```
jewel_fast = input.source(close, title="Select 'The Jewel: Fast'")

tf1     = input.timeframe   ('5', title='Resolution', options=['1','3','5','10','15','30','60','120','240','360','720','D','W','M'])

jewel_fast_htf = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1, jewel_fast)
```

Tried changing input.timeframe to input.string